# Configuring Firebase

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

After moving our project from the Firebase legacy console and updating the pod to version 3.2.0, we need to figure out how to import the GoogleServices-info.plist into our Xcode project. Every time we download the file from the new Firebase console, we get "1.plist" which says error 403 unauthorized. What steps are necessary to obtaining this file?

Comment: I'm having this same problem! Can't seem to get the actual file downloaded.

Comment: I ended up creating a new Firebase project in the new console from scratch. Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i ran into the same issue and found out that in order to generate the GoogleService-Info.plist in the web console your web console login should be recent. So to solve the issue just sign out of firebase and sign in again to refresh your credentials. After that you can try again  to download the plist and it will work

Comment: I apologize, I can't test your solution. I have resulted to alternate means. However, if anyone else happens to verify your solution, I will mark your answer as accepted.